# custom validation, method not allowed on error

Tags: laravel

```
<form method="post" action="{{action('PLAYERController@update', $ply->reg_no)}}">
    {{csrf_field()}}
```

Getting method not allowed exception on  custom validation with false return. Tried mentioning PUT, PATCH and DELETE inside csrf field. Still, does not work.

**UPDATE**

using post for form method. Using method_field('POST'). not defining get method for the update function. If I go back from the error page back to the form page and press refresh, then the validation message is displayed as it should.

**UPDATE 2**

```
Validator::extend('check_sold_amount', function($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {

    if(($value%5000)==0)
    {
        return true;
    }
       return false;
});
    }
```

**UPDATE 3**

Controller code

```
public function update(Request $request, $reg_no)
    {
        //
        $this->validate($request, [
      'sold_amount' => 'required|check_sold_amount',
      'sold_to_team'=>'required'
  ]);
        $ply = Player::find($reg_no);

        $ply->sold_amount = $request->get('sold_amount');
        $ply->sold_to_team = $request->get('sold_to_team');


        $team_name=$ply->sold_to_team;

        $team=Team::find($team_name);
        if($ply->category=='indian')
        {
          $team->indian_players=$team->indian_players+1;
        }
        else {
          $team->foreign_players=$team->foreign_players+1;
        }
        $team->balance=$team->balance-$ply->sold_amount;
        $ply->save();
        $team->save();
        //return view('player.index');

    }
```

Comment: provide route, and blade code

Answer (score 0):

If your update route using `patch` method (example `Route::patch('.....');`) then add this `{{ method_field('PATCH') }}` below `{{csrf_field()}}` in your update form

**UPDATE**

If you are not using `PATCH` method for the update route, try this :

`Route::patch('player/update/{reg_no}', 'PLAYERController@update')->name('plyupdate');`

and then in the form you can do like below :

```
<form method="POST" action="{{route('plyupdate', $ply->reg_no)}}">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    {{ method_field('PATCH') }}
    //Necessary input fields and the submit button here
</form>
```

This way always works fine for me. If it still didn't work, maybe there's something wrong in your update method in the controller

**UPDATE**

Untested, in your update method try this :

```
public function update(Request $request, $reg_no) {
    $input = $request->all();
    $ply = Player::find($reg_no);

    $validate = Validator::make($input, [
        'sold_amount' => 'required|check_sold_amount',
        'sold_to_team'=>'required'
    ]);

    if ($validate->fails()) {
        return back()->withErrors($validate)->withInput();
    }

    $ply->sold_amount = $request->get('sold_amount');
    $ply->sold_to_team = $request->get('sold_to_team');
    $team_name=$ply->sold_to_team;

    $team=Team::find($team_name);
    if($ply->category=='indian') {
        $team->indian_players=$team->indian_players+1;
    }
    else {
        $team->foreign_players=$team->foreign_players+1;
    }
    $team->balance=$team->balance-$ply->sold_amount;
    $ply->save();
    $team->save();

    return view('player.index');
}
```

Don't to forget to add `use Validator;` namespace

Comment: Do you get the error after submitting the form or when you open the page that contains the form ? also if you think this has something to do with your custom validator try to not use it first and see if it works @KenGraham

Comment: when i go back and do refresh , then it comes

Comment: Well, I couldn't figure out what went wrong with your code if my answer did not correct. Maybe you need to provide mote details in your question, like the actual update route you are using and maybe the update method as well @KenGraham

Comment: Everything is working when I add sold_amount in multiples of 5000(which is the validation). But does not work for not multiples of 5000.

Comment: Well, can you please add the custom validation code again in your question ? @KenGraham

Comment: Strange, I reproduced your custom validation rule in my app and it works just fine. @KenGraham

Comment: I suspect this has something to do with your route, updated my answer @KenGraham

Comment: The only problem I see in your method is that you are not redirecting user back to the form if the validation fails. Updated my answer @KenGraham

Comment: still getting the errors. I have updated the code, over here: 
`https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/automatic-redirection-for-custom-validation-not-working`

Answer (score 0):

`Method not allowed` means you do not have a route set up for the request that happened.  There are 2 possibilities:

**The route for the form submission is not set up**

The code you have shown us does not include any `method_field(...)`, so it looks like you are doing a normal `POST`.  So you need a corresponding `POST` route like:

```
Route::post('/some/path', 'PLAYERController@update');
```

**The route for the failed validation response is not set up**

I'm guessing this is the problem.  Say you are on `pageX`, and you landed here via a `POST`.  You have a post route set up, so that you can land on this page OK.  Now from this page, you submit the form you have shown us, but validation fails.  When that happens, Laravel does a `GET` redirect back to `pageX`.  But you have no `GET` route set up for `pageX`, so you'll get a `Method not allowed`.

Along with your `POST` route for the current page, you need a `GET` route to handle failed validations.

Also, you say `Tried mentioning PUT, PATCH and DELETE inside csrf field` - as others pointed out, you should use `method_field()` to spoof form methods, eg:

```
<form ...>
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    {{ method_field('PATCH') }}
```

[Laravel form method spoofing docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#form-method-spoofing)

**UPDATE**

Based on your comments, I think it is actually your initial POST that is failing.  Checking your code again, I think your `action()` syntax is incorrect.

[According to the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-action), if the method specified in the `action()` helper takes parameters, they must be specified as an array:

```
action="{{ action('PLAYERController@update', ['reg_no' => $ply->reg_no]) }}"
```

Comment: Still the error.                                         
`Route::post('/player/update/{reg_no}', 'PLAYERController@update');
Route::get('/player/update/{reg_no}', 'PLAYERController@update');`

Comment: @KenGraham If you watch the network tab of browser dev tools, what is the request that is failing?

Comment: `http://localhost:8000/player/update/555` with post method. `405 method not allowed`

Comment: @KenGraham OK, I think your initial POST is failing bcs your `action()` syntax is wrong.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: Used post for method field and the post error goes away. And redirect shows error.

Comment: when i go back from the error page and do a refresh, and don't use get , i get the validation message as it should.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand where you are or what you are doing now.  If your original question is not accurate (eg it shows you are using post but now you say you are not), maybe you can update it with more details.

Comment: @KenGraham You do not need to use `method_field('POST')` - post is the default, only use `method_field()` if you are using something other than post.  Have you updated your `action()` as I described in my answer update?

Comment: @KenGraham If you click "back", and hit reload, that's a GET, so your get route is working.  The error shows bcs the validation failed, so the validation is working.  If the validation is working, your initial POST is working.  The only thing left is your controller code.  Update your question to include the `PLAYERController@update` method.

Comment: @KenGraham Everything looks fine AFAICT. Only other thing I can think of is you have a route in your routes file, above the 2 you've shown, which is conflicting somehow.  Where is your custom validation code?

Comment: His update method does not redirect user back to the form when the validation fails, that's why he only get to see the error message when he refresh the page

Comment: @PrestonGarvey No, validation does the redirection, not the controller code.  If validation fails, it will automatically redirect back https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic

Comment: If validation **works**, then he needs some redirection or view response, but we're looking at the failure case.

Comment: Well, I thought the auto redirect back only works for the Form Request Class, I was wrong then @Don'tPanic

Comment: @KenGraham I see in your code on laracasts.com you still have `method_field('POST')` - I already described that is incorrect, remove it.  In `PLAYERController.php` go back to the `$this->validate($request, [...` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;

**use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;**

class UserController **extends Controller**
{

```
/**
 * Show the profile for the given user.
```

........................

Did you reference a validation request controller?

Hope this helps :)